# Is it secure to use url.parse to check redirectURL to be only within domain?

Tags: node.js, express, redirect

I need to make secure redirects only within common domain `example.local`. So for example the following are valid: `http://blog.example.local`, `http://www.example.local/dashboard`whereas the following are not: `http://blog.example.local` `http://blog.example.local.fake.com`

```
var url = require('url');

app.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
    var redirect = req.query.redirect,
        targetUrl = url.parse(redirect);

   if (targetUrl.host !== 'example.local') {
      return next(new Error('Open redirect attack detected'));
   }

   return res.redirect(redirect);
});
```

Is it secure enough to use in production or should I fix something?

Comment: Sorry to sound irritating, but how is this different from your [previous question with the same code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37668514/is-preventing-open-redirects-attack-in-nodejs-secure) that's been answered already? Other than the hard-coded host

Comment: I want to be sure in this solution because it's very cricital thing

Comment: Well, the accepted solution in the other post is making use of a whitelist. What you suggest here is essentially a whitelist with only one item, so they're technically equivalent. Don't see why the answers should be differ from the previous ones, but maybe you get some new input, sure...

Answer (score 1):

from your code, if `targetUrl = 'http://blog.example.local'`, your app will return error 'Open redirect attack detected' because targetUrl.host will be 'blog.example.local'

Please change your code a little bit to

```
var expectedHost = [
  'blog.example.local',
  'example.local'
];

if (expectedHost.indexOf(targetUrl.host) === -1) {
  return next(new Error('Open redirect attack detected'));
}
```

then everything will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a allowed domains list somewhere, in DB or in a configuration.json, and validate the return url using RegExp against it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your decision will skip subdomains. I ran this code in repl:

```
23:06 $ node
> var url = require('url')
undefined
> url.parse('http://blog.example.local.fake.com')
{ protocol: 'http:',
  slashes: true,
  auth: null,
  host: 'blog.example.local.fake.com',
  port: null,
  hostname: 'blog.example.local.fake.com',
  hash: null,
  search: null,
  query: null,
  pathname: '/',
  path: '/',
  href: 'http://blog.example.local.fake.com/' }
> url.parse('http://blog.example.local')
{ protocol: 'http:',
  slashes: true,
  auth: null,
  host: 'blog.example.local',
  port: null,
  hostname: 'blog.example.local',
  hash: null,
  search: null,
  query: null,
  pathname: '/',
  path: '/',
  href: 'http://blog.example.local/' }
```

I think it's safe to use simple regex for universal decision, without listing all subdomains:

```
isValidHost = function(host) {
    return /^([^.]+\.)*example.local$/.test(host);
}
```

Maybe better to use more strict regex:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.)*example.local$/
```

I tried on console:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.)*example.com$/.test('xxx..blog.example.com')
false
/^([^.]+\.)*example.com$/.test('xxx..blog.example.com')
false
/^([^.]*\.)*example.com$/.test('xxx.blog.example.com')
true
/^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.)*example.com$/.test('xxxexample.com')
false
/^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.)*example.com$/.test('example.com')
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the whole code to prevent Open Redirection attack issue, It will check your URL and validate that it is under same domain or not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
               function LaunchHelp() {
            try {

                var surl = "http://www.google.com";
                if (validateURL(surl))
                    window.open(surl, '_blank', 'toolbar=no,menubar=no,status=yes');
                else {
                    throw new InvalidURLException();
                }
            } catch (e) {
                if (e instanceof InvalidURLException)
                    alert(e.message);
            }
        }

        function InvalidURLException() {
            this.message = "An attempt was made to open a webpage of foreign domain. No allowed.";
            this.toString = function () {
                return this.message
            };
        }

        function validateURL(surl) {
            var url = parseURL(surl);
            var urlHostname = url.hostname.trim();

            if (urlHostname == '') {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                if (urlHostname.toUpperCase() == location.hostname.trim().toUpperCase()) {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }

        function parseURL(url) {
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = url;
            return {
                source: url,
                protocol: a.protocol.replace(':', ''),
                hostname: a.hostname,
                host: a.host,
                port: a.port,
                query: a.search,
                params: (function () {
                    var ret = {},
                        seg = a.search.replace(/^\?/, '').split('&'),
                        len = seg.length, i = 0, s;
                    for (; i < len; i++) {
                        if (!seg[i]) { continue; }
                        s = seg[i].split('=');
                        ret[s[0]] = s[1];
                    }
                    return ret;
                })(),
                file: (a.pathname.match(/\/([^\/?#]+)$/i) || [, ''])[1],
                hash: a.hash.replace('#', ''),
                path: a.pathname.replace(/^([^\/])/, '/$1'),
                relative: (a.href.match(/tps?:\/\/[^\/]+(.+)/) || [, ''])[1],
                segments: a.pathname.replace(/^\//, '').split('/')
            };
        }



    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is Test 1 Page.</h1>
    <button id="btnRedirect" name="btnRedirect" onclick="LaunchHelp()">Redirect</button>
</body>
</html>
```

You can just replace your url in place of this line of code.

```
var surl = "http://www.google.com";
```

Hope this will help you.
thanks